# Fluent NHibernate configuration for uni-directional one-to-many relation - Issue on Delete

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I've got an Address class with a collection of DeliveryDays.
The mapping is as follow (found on this brilliant site!=):

```
HasMany(x => x.DeliveryDays)
                .KeyColumn("AddressId")
                .Not.Inverse() 
                .Not.KeyNullable() 
                .Not.KeyUpdate() 
                .Cascade.All();
```

My DeliveryDay class holds no reference to Address and I would rather not to!

That all works great when adding an item to the collection, but not at all when removing one: SQL Delete is not generated !

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an exact answer I think you'll need to post some more code. Based on the code you've posted so far my guess is that you want to use **Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan() instead of Cascade.All()**.

Cascade option All will only trigger a delete on DeliveryDay if the associated Address is deleted while cascade option AllDeleteOrphan will trigger a delete when a DeliveryDay is removed from the associated Address (as long as it is not associated with a different Address).